# How does both the / and \\ comes at the same time in file path in windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I was doing data preprocessing and got stuck with an issue. When I do some extraction from the . XML file, the resulting file path has both forward slash and backward slash occurs. Why is this happening and how can I rectify it?

```
path = glob('./images/*.xml')
print(path)
labels_dict = dict(filepath=[],xmin=[],xmax=[],ymin=[],ymax=[])
for filename in path:
    print(filename)
    info = xet.parse(filename)
    root = info.getroot()
    member_object = root.find('object')
    labels_info = member_object.find('bndbox')
    xmin = int(labels_info.find('xmin').text)
    xmax = int(labels_info.find('xmax').text)
    ymin = int(labels_info.find('ymin').text)
    ymax = int(labels_info.find('ymax').text)
    labels_dict['filepath'].append(filename)
    labels_dict['xmin'].append(xmin)
    labels_dict['xmax'].append(xmax)
    labels_dict['ymin'].append(ymin)
    labels_dict['ymax'].append(ymax)
```

The result comes while executing the script is:

```
['./images\\N1.xml', './images\\N100.xml']
./images\N1.xml
./images\N100.xml
```

Comment: If you don't want that, use `os.sep` or a call that uses it instead of hardcoding `/` in the path you pass to `glob()`. For example, you can get the same effect with `os.path.join('.', 'images', '*.xml')`

Comment: This is harmless as Windows can internally cope with such mixed paths. If you want to fix it, there is the `replace` method of strings.

Comment: Anyhow -- as the output should make obvious, `glob()` just prepends the prefix you give it to the output names, so the "why" is not very mysterious. After all, if it's a prefix you provided, it's a prefix you consider correct, so it's a prefix that it's reasonable and correct for the output to use... right?

Answer (score 0):

Although this mixing of path separators doesn't particularly matter (as Python/Windows will handle it correctly either way), if you don't want to use `os.path.join()` to construct your paths, you can use [`os.path.normpath()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to "normalize" path strings after the fact. I would recommend this over the `str.replace()` method.

On Windows:

```py
>>> import os
>>> os.path.normpath('./images\\N100.xml')
'images\\N100.xml'
```